# Pop-up the footer with jquery on website with FIRST clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have issue for pop-up the footer with jquery. My code is work but the only problem is it doesn't work with the first click on the button, it work by second clicking on the button? any idea?
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function($) {

        var open = false;

        $('#footerSlideButton').click(function () {

            if(open === false) {

                $('#footerSlideContainer').animate({ height: '0' });

                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');

                open = true;

            } else {

                $('#footerSlideContainer').animate({ height: '150px' });

                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');

                open = false;

            }

        });        

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Should `var open = true;` be `var open = false;`?

Comment: Side note: for `if` statements, if the var is a bool, you can simply say `if(open)` for true, `if(!open)` for false

Comment: oops..sorry, if it was false I have the same problem too. It works by second click on the button. I want with the first click the footer pop up..Do you think its related to the css??

Answer (score 0):

I would condense it to this:

```
(function($){
    window.opened=false;
    $('#footerSlideButton').on('click', function () {
        $('#footerSlideContainer').animate({ height : opened ? '0' : '150px'});
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', opened ? 'top left' : 'bottom left');
        opened = !opened;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

you could also store the open state in the element data:

```
(function($){
    $('#footerSlideButton').on('click', function () {
        $('#footerSlideContainer').animate({ height : $(this).data('open') ? '0' : '150px'});
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', $(this).data('open') ? 'top left' : 'bottom left');
        $(this).data('open', !$(this).data('open'));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why are you using `window.open` inside of a function?  I wouldn't suggest that.  It *should* be `var open = false;` P.S. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open

Comment: I agree with you windows.open doesn't work. Both above code doesn't work!!

Comment: yea, window.open was a big oversight on my part.

Comment: Even I changed the windows.open the footer doesn't pop up but with my code its pop up but with second clicking!!!

Comment: you need to provide your code then, because it works on fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/BbnLc/

Comment: yea, it works on fiddler!! Is it possible because of the version of jquery that I used? I used jquery 1.6.1 ??

Comment: if you can't upgrade your version of jQuery, you can substitute `.click(function` for `.on('click', function` and it should work for you.